# Changing from php mail() to wp_mail() for submitting form

Tags: php, phpmailer, wp-mail

Recently the hostingprovider has disabled for its customers sending forms with php mail(). Users can submit a form which looks like this, which always worked fine.
How do i change this mail() to send with wp_mail().
I have already installed WP Mail SMTP which is working, but this is a custom form that has to be changed sending with wp_mail() instead of mail(). Thanks!

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['set']))
{
    $_SESSION['set'] = 1;
    $oConnect       = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'userlogin', 'userpass');
    $content    = str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $content);

    //DATA pulled from DB 

    $to         = $_POST['txt_email']; 
    $subject    = 'Your request';
    $headers    = "From: info@domainexample.com\r\n";
    $headers    .= "Bcc: info@domainexmaple.com\r\n";
    $headers    .= "Reply-To: info@domainexample.com\r\n";
    $headers    .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers    .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    // send mail
    if(!empty($to)){
       mail($to,$subject,$content,$headers); 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at [the PHPMailer docs on WordPress](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-PHPMailer-in-WordPress).

Comment: What have you tried, and how exactly did it not work? `wp_mail` takes the same parameters in the same order, according to its documentation, as you already have there in your `mail` call.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!
The reason why wp_mail did not work and therefore plugins like WP Mail SMTP also didn't work was because wp-load was not called. If this is not called, then only `mail()` function works and not `wp_mail()`.

To solve this, simply put this directly after `<?php`:

```
require_once("../wp-load.php");
```

By adding this, the `wp_mail()` function gets called instead of `mail()` if you use something like `wp_mail($to,$subject,$headers);`